# Why does neofetch say my shell is Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Neofetch says my shell is bash.  However, I was under the impression that i changed my default shell to zsh with the chsh command.

`Echo $0` shows zsh as my current shell, and `echo $SHELL` shows bash as my default shell.

How do I get zsh to be the default, and will neofetch be able to reflect this?

Comment: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/issues/829

Comment: Thank you, this contained a solution.  Added line to .zshrc ```export SHELL=zsh```, seems to have done the trick.  Now neofetch correctly reflects my shell.

Comment: @InvaderVim Since the problem is solved, can you close the question, pleas?